# How can I correct color banding in windows phone 7?

Tags: colors, windows-phone-7, photoshop

My windows phone 7 app has very nice background images but they are being destroyed by color banding on a 16bit color device. Is there a way I can correct this? I have tried saving in several different modes in photoshop to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use dithering. [Floyd-Steinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Steinberg) is a good algorithm that is simple and runs fast.

You don't need to go to 8 bits per pixel as suggested by another answer, you can go directly to 16 bits per pixel. You need to know how it is split into R/G/B before you begin.

Here are some examples, first up is the original 24-bit:

[image]

Next is a 16-bit without dithering:

[image]

Finally 16-bit with Floyd-Steinberg dithering.

[image]

P.S. I did this with Paint Shop Pro, I don't know if Photoshop has anything similar. You can do it in code as well.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed! Anyone know how to achieve this in Photoshop and get it to save properly?

Comment: @Jamey, that sounds like another good question... not one for this forum I'm afraid. If I get bored I might whip up a Python script to do it, but it will be in my spare time and won't be soon. ImageMagick might also be able to do it with a `-depth 5` switch.

Comment: @Jamey, you can definitely convert to 16 bits in Photoshop, but I don't know whether it applies dithering. http://forums.adobe.com/message/1904192

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate all your comments.

Comment: @JameyMcElveen, I know it has been ages since you asked this question but I finally did my own implementation (in C++): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640017/what-is-a-good-optimized-c-c-algorithm-for-converting-a-24-bit-bitmap-to-16-b/11650801#11650801

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to not use gradients directly.
There is no way round this with the colours supported by the device.

The alternative is to create a dithered image and use that instead.

Comment: are the downvotes beccause that's not what people want to hear? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Probably because it's not what people want to hear.  They'd rather you sprinked magic software-fairy dust and have it fix their hardware with 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If I set the mode to 8bit and dither using the "web palette" this creates a pretty good result. This is MUCH better looking than the banded image. However I will probably end up with 2 versions of the background image. One for 16 bit and one for 24 bit and above.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go if you have Photoshop.

[Photoshop Action for Windows Phone 7 Dithering](http://nerdplusart.com/photoshop-action-for-windows-phone-7-dithering)

The "download"-image link is broken.
So use the download link in the "How to Install and Use It" list.