# Reduce color bandings to create GIF from at most 200 video frames using Swift/Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, gif, 256color

I want to make GIF from video frames. Per frame (UIImage) size is at most **960 * 540**.
As GIF is bound to 256 colors, I got more colors issues. frames are poorly generated.
After so many research, I've found [Dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) approach that may reduce [color bandings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding). 
 I didn't go with this approach because default time complexity of dithering is O(N^2) where N is the multiplication of Image's width and height. I don't know how to reduce color banding efficiently without dithering for 200 frames. Is there any other technique or filter available which can reduce color banding efficiently? 
Original Video : [Original video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19v7Epy-qIf8GYSOOTkLXK0eaPrwVBuQr/view?usp=sharing) 
The GIF I produced : [my GIF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ln7ST_dGNcp2oruqSgb8NAy0QzGVOdJg/view?usp=sharing) 
The GIF I need : [better-GIF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mLx0VAo5-r0X5bzt4kVt5TpzZ7U7azsg/view?usp=sharing)

My Approach: First I saved all frames as UIImage from Video. then I created GIF using following code :

```
func generateImagesToGif(photos: [UIImage], filename: String) -> Bool {
        let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let path = documentsDirectoryPath.appending(filename)
        let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]
        let gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: 0.5]]
        let cfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) as CFURL
        if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(cfURL, kUTTypeGIF, photos.count, nil) {
            CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties as CFDictionary?)
            for photo in photos {
                CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, photo.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)
            }
            return CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
        }
        return false
    }
```

Update : Have a look this ([High Quality GIF](https://www.reddit.com/r/HighQualityGifs/comments/p5115d/some_parts_of_this_movie_feel_like_they_have_aged/)). Their GIF looks like original video. Very low color bandings!

Comment: What are 'color bandings'?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding @ElTomato

Comment: Oh, okay.  Thanks.  I thought they are called color-bindings.

Comment: But these approach returned poor result. I need to produce better GIF which looks more natural. @EricAya

Comment: May be in this case, dithering is not the proper way I guess.

Comment: Most dithering algorithms don't have a complexity of O(N²) but just O(N), e.g. Floyd-Steinberg dithering. And dithering is required to avoid the banding due to color quantization.

Comment: So , in my case to produce  more natural GIF, what should I do now? Which approach I need to follow? @Codo

Comment: GIF images are restricted to 256 colors. So a *color quantization* step is needed to find the closest color from the table. It should  be combined with a *dithering* step to distribute the quantization error to neighboring pixels. I am not aware of a built-in iOS framework that can do this. *CIDither* certainly doesn't help as it is a filter to add noise. And I don't think the *Accelerate* framework helps either. You will probably have to look for a specialized color quantization library such as [https://github.com/ImageOptim/libimagequant](libimagequant).

Comment: Check https://github.com/topics/color-quantization . One relatively simple algo you could do is popularity algorithm. It reduces number of colors and seeks the nearest (RGB wise) one still in palette for every pixel.

Comment: Here is an example of Floyd-Steinberg dithering from 24 bit to 16 bit color: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640017/what-is-a-good-optimized-c-c-algorithm-for-converting-a-24-bit-bitmap-to-16-b You could try implementing something similar to process pixels of your UIImage to 8 bit color https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monochrome_and_RGB_color_formats#8-bit_RGB_(also_known_as_3-3-2_bit_RGB) before you add them to your gif file.

Comment: Hi @LeszekSzary, I don't have permission to comment from stackOverflow. can you help me ? I go through to your link. which value I need to change if I convert UIImage to 8 bit color?
I go though this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438757/13671576

Comment: Look this. (https://www.reddit.com/r/HighQualityGifs/comments/p5115d/some_parts_of_this_movie_feel_like_they_have_aged/ )
Their GIF is like original video. It looks very low color banding.